# Spring reactive Rest xml payload

Tags: spring, reactive, spring-webflux

I am sending the request through postman to try the rest payload with spring reactive programming
**Controller**

```
@RestController
        public class WBController {
        @PostMapping(value="/transform", consumes="application/xml", produces="application/xml")
            @ResponseBody 

            public Mono<Extractdata> tranformTechnicalMetadata(Mono<Extractdata> data) {
             return data;
        }
```

**POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.gateway</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>com-microservice</name>
    <description>reactive Project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web-reactive</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.M4</version>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
            </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.ipc</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

**Pojo Class**

i

```
mport java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;



@XmlRootElement(name="extractdata")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

public class Extractdata {

    @XmlElement(name="inputName")
    private String inputName;
    @XmlElement(name="inputValue")
    private String inputValue;
    public String getInputName() {
        return inputName;
    }
    public void setInputName(String inputName) {
        this.inputName = inputName;
    }
    public String getInputValue() {
        return inputValue;
    }
    public void setInputValue(String inputValue) {
        this.inputValue = inputValue;
    }
}
```

**Sample Request**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<extractdata>
   <inputName>ship</inputName>
    <inputValue>TURNE</inputValue>
    </extractdata>
```

**Response**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
        <extractMetadataEx/>
```

Problem with response is not getting the full data. Pojo the inputName and inputvalue is null.
 **expected output**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <extractdata>
       <inputName>ship</inputName>
        <inputValue>TURNE</inputValue>
        </extractdata>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: remove the `spring-mvc-reactive` dependency that is superseded with `spring-webflux` which is already part of the `spring-boot-starter-webflux`. You have a lot of duplicate (and conflicting?) dependencies, start by cleaning up.

Comment: M.Deinum is right about your dependencies. At that point, I'd even regenerate a clean project with start.spring.io (choose Boot 2.0 and reactive web).

Comment: Thank you for the response. As advised I started a new project

Comment: Thank you for the response. As advised I started a new project. Now when I send the xml payload I get exception  though with json paylod I get the expected response. Please advise            java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to resolve argument 0 of type 'reactor.core.publisher.Mono' on public reactor.core.publisher.Mono<com.event.gateway.rest.controller.Sir> com.event.gateway.rest.controller.WBController.hello(reactor.core.publisher.Mono<com.event.gateway.rest.controller.Sir>)com.event.gateway.rest.controller.WBController.hello(reactor.core.publisher.Mono
 at

Comment: @pk.avj Probably you have the same problem as here http://stackoverflow.com/a/42552059/2055854